# where can i find asp.net neatupload demo application?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use: neatupload and I have got many errors... I found this demo working here: 
http://www.brettle.com/Demo.aspx

Does anybody know where can I download this demo?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The demo is right inside the [download package](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I have downloaded the package but it does not contain the demo. please correct me if I am worng

Comment: @devn, it's inside the `NeatUpload` folder in the zip. The `bin` folder contains the binaries.

Comment: @devn Could you help me with installing the demo at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391657/how-to-install-neatupload ?  Thanks!

Comment: @devn - never mind that last comment.  I figured it out.  For anyone who needs help getting the demo to work, just check out the post I mentioned in the preceeding comment.

Comment: What about a demo for a client application?  That doesn't ship with the neatupload package.